# Search and replace using a variable

Tags: replace, visual-studio-code

I want to search for all occurences :

```
$elem->something
```

and replace it with

```
$elem['something']
```

Is there a way to search and replace using vscode by passing a variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure,
you can search and replace using capturing groups

My first shot:
search: `\$elem->(.*)\b`
replace: `$elem['$1']`

Second shot:
search `\$elem->([^ ]*)\b`
replace: `$elem['$1']`

Make sure you enable the case sensitive and regular expression flags.

[image: search]

The result should be:

[image: result]